# How to test warnings with Pytest but exclude from summary report

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest supports testing for warning messages with warns(). For example,

auth.py:

```
import warnings


def warn_for_plain_text_security():
    warnings.warn("Notice: Credentials in the .rc file is deprecated") 

warn_for_plain_text_security()
```

test_auth.py:

```
import unittest
import warnings
import pytest
from auth import warn_for_plain_text_security


class AuthProviderTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_insecure_creds(self):
        with pytest.warns(UserWarning, match='Notice:') as w:
            warn_for_plain_text_security()
```

However, the warnings -- which are really just successful unit tests -- then show up in the summary report.

I want to be able to test Python warnings, but only see **real** warnings in the summary. Is there a way to do this?

```
===================================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.8, pytest-8.0.1, pluggy-1.4.0
rootdir: /private/tmp
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                               

test_auth.py .                                                                                                                                                                           [100%]

================== warnings summary ==================
auth.py:5
  /private/tmp/auth.py:5: UserWarning: Notice: Credentials in the .rc file is deprecated
    warnings.warn("Notice: Credentials in the .rc file is deprecated")

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
============ 1 passed, 1 warning in 0.02s ============
```

There is a [WarningsRecorder](https://docs.pytest.org/en/8.0.x/how-to/capture-warnings.html#recwarn) instance, but it's unclear if this can be manipulated during the test case.

Comment: Post all the code. If the warnings match your expression they are not printed in the summary.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem, the originally, test_insecure_creds() was being called twice in the unit tests, but warnings only reports one warning text because duplicates are suppressed.

When I added the "with pytest.warns", that caught one of the warnings but the other one was still unhandled.

The documentation on warns could be clearer on this, but it works as it should.